# Change android primary color

Tags: java, android, android-color

I created an app where I basically changed all of its colors and styles.
However, there are places where I can still see that the app uses the default primary green color such as:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to make the app use my color instead of this green? I changed it everywhere I could think

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#8275FE</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#8275FE</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#8275FE</color>
    <color name="colorWhite">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorLightPurple">#8275FE</color>
    <color name="colorDarkPurple">#8140FE</color>
    <color name="colorPhrase">#CDD34D</color>
    <color name="colorGray">#8C8C8C</color>
    <color name="colorLightGray">#BEBEBE</color>
    <color name="colorGrayText">#707070</color>
    <color name="colorGraySearch">#EDEFF3</color>
    <color name="colorGraySearchText">#FFA09F9F</color>
    <color name="colorEmptyStar">#707070</color>
    <color name="colorFullStar">#F0BA01</color>
    <color name="colorRed">#F30000</color>
    <color name="colorBlackText">#191919</color>
    <color name="colorFB">#3B589C</color>
    <color name="colorPurpleChat">#E6E3FE</color>
    <color name="colorGrayChat">#F2F2F2</color>
    <color name="colorGraySeekBar">#E0E0E0</color>
    <color name="colorGrayBox">#F6F7F9</color>
    <color name="colorLockedPurple">#BAB2FE</color>
</resources>
```

(none of them is that green), and:

```
<style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorGraySearchText</item>
    <item name="background">@color/colorGraySearch</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorGraySearchText</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
</style>

<style name="rb_Stars" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorEmptyStar</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorFullStar</item>
</style>

<style name="CalenderViewCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorLightGray</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorLightPurple</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorGrayText</item>
</style>

<style name="CalenderViewDateCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorLightPurple</item>
    <item name="android:weekNumberColor">@color/colorLightPurple</item>
</style>

<style name="CalenderViewWeekCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorLightPurple</item>
</style>
```

The code for that `TextView` for example:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_Terms1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/assistant_semibold"
    android:background="@color/fui_transparent"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:text="@string/ActivitySignUp_Terms1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_SignUpPassword" />
```

Comment: probably a stupid question but did you assign the style correctly?

Comment: Your second image is from a soft keyboard. I forget if there is a way to hint at a preferred accent color. But, even if there is, there are dozens, if not hundreds, of soft keyboard implementations. Do not assume that they all will honor any requested color. Your first image appears to be from your own UI. You might wish to include in your [mcve] how you are creating that UI.

Comment: Added, it is basically a regular textview from what I understand

Comment: For the color link add in your app theme `<item name="android:textColorLink">@color/....</item>`